# Why does Java regex engine throw StringIndexOutOfBoundsException on a + repetition?

Tags: java, regex, fibonacci, nested-reference

I've written a regex pattern to find Fibonacci numbers (it doesn't matter why, I just did). It works wonderfully as expected ([see on ideone.com](http://ideone.com/vlVqj)):

```
    String FIBONACCI = 
        "(?x) .{0,2} | (?: (?=(\\2?)) (?=(\\2\\3|^.)) (?=(\\1)) \\2)++ . ";

    for (int n = 0; n < 1000; n++) {
        String s = new String(new char[n]);
        if (s.matches(FIBONACCI)) {
            System.out.print(n + " ");
        }
    } // 0 1 2 3 5 8 13 21 34 55 89 144 233 377 610 987
```

A [possessive](http://www.regular-expressions.info/possessive.html) repetition (i.e. `++` on the main "loop") is crucial, because you don't want backtracking with this matching algorithm. However, making the repetition backtrackable (i.e. just `+` on the main "loop") results not in mismatches, but rather a runtime exception!!! ([as seen on ideone.com](http://ideone.com/6FeXG)):

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException:
    String index out of range: -1

    at java.lang.String.charAt(String.java:686)
    at java.lang.Character.codePointAt(Character.java:2335)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$CharProperty.match(Pattern.java:3344)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupCurly.match0(Pattern.java:3994)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupCurly.match0(Pattern.java:3966)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$GroupCurly.match(Pattern.java:3916)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern$Branch.match(Pattern.java:4114)
    at java.util.regex.Matcher.match(Matcher.java:1127)
    at java.util.regex.Matcher.matches(Matcher.java:502)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.matches(Pattern.java:930)
    at java.lang.String.matches(String.java:2090)
```

Can someone explain what happened here? Is this a bug in the Java regex engine?

Comment: I bet it is because the regex engine is just plain tired of being asked to do silly things :-).

Comment: Finding fibonacci numbers with *regex*? poly, you're crazy!

Comment: @Stephen: there's a quote like "if you don't know at least _N_ ways to break something, you haven't really understood it yet", so that's all I'm trying to do is learn. @Andreas: Hey, the `++` version works! Now I just need to understand why the `+` raises an exception, and how to port this algorithm to .NET which doesn't have possessive repetition.

Comment: now that's a messed up regular exception... :-) still trying to get my head around your regexp...

Comment: @aioobe: once I fully understood this issue, I plan to fully explain how the algorithm works as an example of nested reference and possessive quantifier usage.

Comment: Looks like a bug. If it helps, it seems to pass 4 and fail on 5 (which should match) - http://ideone.com/EXStT . I was also bored lately and did something related with a [balancing group](http://kobikobi.wordpress.com/2010/09/06/using-net-regex-balancing-groups-to-match-words-in-fibonacci-lengths/), but that isn't quite as difficult :)

Comment: For what it's worth, even a backtrackable repetition in .NET works (http://ideone.com/yB16g). I thought for sure backtracking will cause mismatches. I guess even I don't fully understand my own algorithm =).

Comment: @poly - there's another saying: "Too much knowledge is a dangerous thing".

Answer (score 11):

## Bug ID 6984178

There are many bugs related to the engine throwing `StringIndexOutOfBoundsException` ([see: search results](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-6984178?jql=text%20~%20%22regex%20stringindexoutofboundsexception%22). This one in particular has been reported and internally accepted as [Bug ID 6984178](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-6984178) (it may take a while for this to show up in the external database).

Here's a much simpler pattern that reproduces the bug ([see also on ideone.com](http://ideone.com/OrrWa)):

```
System.out.println(
   "abaab".matches("(?x) (?: (?=(a+)) \\1 b )* x")
); // StringIndexOutOfBounds: -1
```

Note that using `*?` or `*+` simply returns `false` as expected.

It looks like the problem is triggered by the attempt to backtrack a greedy repetition when there's a reference to a capturing group inside a lookahead: the out of bounds index is the difference in length between the first and the second `a+` (e.g. `"aabaaaaab"` gets `-3`).

One would likely have to debug the [`java.util.regex.Pattern` source code](http://www.google.com/codesearch/p?hl=en#av_p04Hv9fs/src/share/classes/java/util/regex/Pattern.java) to pinpoint the exact nature of the bug.

---

## Exploring the Fibonacci pattern

#### On the Java engine, with greedy backtracking `+`

Here's a more verbose snippet to show just how bonkers the engine gets on this pattern:

```
String FIBONACCI = 
    "(?x) .{0,2} | (?: (?=(\\2|^)) (?=(\\2\\3|^.)) (?=(\\1)) \\2)+ . ";

for (int n = 0; n < 1000; n++) {
    String s = new String(new char[n]);
    try {
        if (s.matches(FIBONACCI)) {
            System.out.printf("%n%s", n);
        }
    } catch (StringIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
        String index = e.getMessage().replace("String index out of range: ", "");
        System.out.printf(" <%s:%s>", n, index);
    }
}
```

The (slightly edited) output is ([as seen on ideone.com](http://ideone.com/dzBF1)):

```
0 1 2 3 <5:-1>
6 <7:-1> ... <12:-1> <13:-3>
14 <15:-3> ... <33:-3> <34:-8>
35 <36:-8> ... <88:-8> <89:-21>
90 <91:-21> ... <232:-21> <233:-55>
234 <235:-55> ... <609:-55> <610:-144>
611 <612:-144> ...
```

So somehow the engine tries to access string indices at -1, -3, -8, -21, -55, -144, etc. Note that these are every other Fibonacci number, but negative. Note also that beyond the first few numbers, the rest of the matches (6, 14, 35, ...) are *NOT* Fibonacci numbers.

---

#### On the .NET engine, with greedy backtracking `+`

While the pattern was originally written with the necessity for possessive quantifier in mind, in fact a backtracking repetition will still yield the correct answer (assuming the engine isn't buggy like Java's). Here's a C# implementation on the .NET engine ([see also on ideone.com](http://ideone.com/6hN9G)):

```
Regex r = new Regex(
  @"(?x) ^.{0,1}$ | ^(?: (?=(\2?)) (?=(\2\3|^.)) (?=(\1)) \2)+ . $ "
);

for (int n = 0; n < 1000; n++) {
  if (r.IsMatch("".PadLeft(n))) {
    Console.Write("{0} ", n);
  }
}
// 0 1 2 3 5 8 13 21 34 55 89 144 233 377 610 987
```

As you can see, the output is correct, even with a backtracking `+` "loop". In fact, precisely because it's a backtracking loop, the special case can be limited to just `.{0,1}` instead of `.{0,2}`.

---

#### On the Java engine, with reluctant backtracking `+?`

This works in Java as expected. Also, because it's reluctant, we can also limit the special case to just `.{0,1}` ([see also on ideone.com](http://ideone.com/w6Xqx)):

```
String FIBONACCI = 
        "(?x) .{0,1} | (?: (?=(\\2|^)) (?=(\\2\\3|^.)) (?=(\\1)) \\2)+? . ";
```

---

## On the algorithm

#### The formula

The pattern exploits the [Second Identity of Fibonacci Numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number):

[image]

This can be proven by induction.

#### The pattern

Let's use this version of the pattern (which works in Java, and when anchored, also works in C#):

```
                                                     summation 
free-space!                                            "loop"
    ↓                                                     ↓
   (?x) .{0,1} | (?: (?=(\2|^)) (?=(\2\3|^.)) (?=(\1)) \2)+? .
        \____/   \___________________________________/  ↑    ↑  
      base case      inductive case                    +Fi  +1
     for n = 0,1
                     (assertions don't "count" toward sum)!
                        $1 := $2    (or initialized with 0)
                        $2 := $2+$3 (or initialized with 1)
                        $3 := $1    (a temporary variable for the "swap")
```

The Fibonacci sequence generation is straightforward, based on the `[$1, $2] := [$2, $2+$1]` transition. Since the assertions are performed sequentially, a temporary variable is introduced (just like the single-assignment "pseudocode" version).

Comment: FYI, most of those bug reports concern malformed regexes or replacement strings and how they're handled.  The only bug is that it should throw a PatternSyntaxException (regex) or an IllegalArgumentException (replacement), not a SIOOBE.  I've tried to get them to change that, to no avail.