# Replace text in StringBuilder via regex

Tags: java, regex, stringbuilder

I would like to replace some texts in StringBuilder. How to do this?

In this code I got `java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException` at line with `matcher.find()`:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(input);
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(str_pattern);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(sb);
while (matcher.find())
  sb.replace(matcher.start(), matcher.end(), "x");
```

Answer (score 4):

Lets have a StringBuilder w/ 50 total length and you change the first 20chars to 'x'. So the StringBuilder is shrunk by 19, right - however the initial input pattern.matcher(sb) is not altered, so in the end StringIndexOutOfBoundsException.

Answer (score 2):

I've solved this by adding `matcher.reset()`:

```
    while (matcher.find())
    {
        sb.replace(matcher.start(), matcher.end(), "x");
        matcher.reset();
    }
```

Comment: With `str_pattern = "x"` and `input = "x"` you get an endless loop. With `str_pattern = "xx"` and `input = "xxxx"` you get a wrong result (`"x"` instead of `"xx"`).

Comment: Adding matcher.reset() is not working. I'm still getting the same exception.

Answer (score 1):

This is already a reported bug and I'm guessing they're currently looking into a fix for it. Read more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3698407/why-does-java-regex-engine-throw-stringindexoutofboundsexception-on-a-repetitio).

Comment: yea sorry i couldn't offer any better solution.

Comment: how is that a bug? you alter the content and length/position of the StringBuilder but you don't touch the former string, you should compensate the delta.

Comment: there is no bug. I found solution: matcher.reset()

Comment: This is no bug and it's completely unrelated to the link.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't do it this way. The input to Matcher may be any CharSequence, but the sequence should not change. Matching like you do is like iterating over a Collection while removing elements at the same time, this can't work.

However, maybe there's a solution:

```
while (matcher.find()) {
    sb.replace(matcher.start(), matcher.end(), "x");
    matcher.region(matcher.start() + "x".length(), sb.length());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe:

```
    int lookIndex = 0;
    while (lookIndex < builder.length() && matcher.find(lookIndex)) {
        lookIndex = matcher.start()+1;
        builder.replace(matcher.start(), matcher.end(), repl);
    }
```

...?

.find(n) with an integer argument claims to reset the matcher before it starts looking at the specified index. That would work around the issues raised in maartinus comment above.

Comment: No, sorry it won't, and it can't handle two successive strings that match the pattern either :(

Answer (score 0):

Another issue with using StringBuidler.replace() is that that one can't handle capturing groups.