# Matcher find() method returns StringOutOfBounds exception

Tags: java, regex, indexoutofboundsexception

I just started using Java regular expressions at work, and am having trouble with using the Matcher find() method.

In the following code, i is a String parameter received from the client, and 'list' is a ready made linked list with String values, and I want to find the value in the list that appears in i at the smallest possible index out of all the other list values (if there is indeed a match). The values in the list might have an asterisk at their end, which means they have a wildcard, so there are 0 or more 'word characters' in their end - so I have to consider that when searching in i. Here is the code:

```
Pattern checkRegex;
        int tStart = i.length(); 
        for (String t : list){
            if (t.charAt(t.length()-1) == '*')
                checkRegex = Pattern.compile("\\W" + t + "[0-9A-Za-z]*\\W");
            else
                checkRegex = Pattern.compile("\\W" + t + "\\W");
            Matcher regexMatcher = checkRegex.matcher(i);
            if (regexMatcher.find()){
                if (tStart > i.indexOf(regexMatcher.regionStart()))
                    tStart = i.indexOf(regexMatcher.regionStart());
            }
```

I get the error - Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -1

After debugging, I found that the program crashes at the regexMatcher.find() command - but since it is a boolean method, I don't understand what String indexes have to do here.

Appreciate your help.

Comment: Have a look at this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4829908/replace-text-in-stringbuilder-via-regex Maybe can help you

Comment: can you provide the complete stacktrace?

Comment: not using brackets does *not* make you more clever.

Comment: your comment doesn't either.

Comment: @Ozilophile I'm editing out the exception you added, because the answer given by TheLostMind seems to have solved your problem. That exception you've added after that answer is completely different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`t.length()-1` is the problem. What if t is empty `""`? . You need to make a null and empty check before you call `t.charAt()`

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but it didn't work. I edited my post with adding the code you'd suggested, please let me know if you see the problem now.

Comment: @Ozilophile - can you give complete program?. What is `i`, what is `list`?

Comment: i is a title of a product - example - Samsung Galaxy S3 Mini (GT-i8190) Factory Unlocked International Version - WHITE.

list is a LinkedList of keywords (strings) - example - "plus", "with" and so on (without quotes, of course).